# Git : Should I Revert and Review?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

My team and I are working with GitLab, and we are still beginners at using Git, I made some changes and I want to commit them, should I pull or push before? I tried to pull before committing the changes and always get : you may revert or review and commit...

Comment: I think your question is a little broad. Typically, you want to have some base that everyone spawns from (master or dev branch), and do *modular* work in other branches. Then, you commit as often as you like in the particular branch you've spawned off master, and can push those branches up independently to the repo. When you're happy with the state of your branch, make a pull request (merge request) into master (i.e. updating master). Or just merge without request, if that's your flow.

Comment: We did that and my question is concerning the conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're really not familiar at all with git.

Before anything else, I highly suggest that you read a lot of [documentation on git alone and its mechanics](https://git-scm.com/).

In your case, you should commit your changes on your local repository (on your computer if you prefer). Only then you will pull (that means get the new changes from the "server").

You may have some conflicts if some other people have made modifications on the same code you made changes on. In that case, you must resolve the conflicts in one of the three manners : you chose to ignore your changes and take the version of the server (aka the "main remote" often called origin), you chose to ignore the version of the server and keep only your changes, or the most complicated solution, you modify the file that have conflicts and keep for each conflict in the file.

Once you have done that, you can push to the server, that means that your modifications are put on the server and other team members can get them from it.

I hope it helps but again, you really should read documentation and understand some basic key words from git world and basic principles. Good luck for the following.

EDIT:As far as I know, there is no magic spell to solve conflicts automagically if it is your question. If each person in your team is working on different branches, the only moment where conflicts may appear is on a merge process, and as I said, in this case, the conflict management should really be made manually to avoid all sort of unexpected errors/behaviors/features/bugs.

Comment: well I usually solve the issue and I'm familiar with the git but I wanted a permanent fix for the conflicts or which comes first after modifying my branch, pulling or pushing, so it's committing and pushing to my branch, then pulling from master and resolving manually like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple answer for you and it comes from my daily experience, just go ahead commit your changes right away anytime, then you do `git pull --rebase` right before your `git push`